# Importance of timing attack resistance with AES

Tags: aes, timing-attack

I've implemented AES in my library with several variations: a straight C version, a version using x86 SSSE3, and a version using x86 AES-NI.  The SSSE3 and AES-NI implementations are constant-time, whereas the C implementation uses lookup tables.

My SSSE3 implementation is a bit (~20%) slower than my C implementation.  It doesn't use bit-slicing, so as to support CBC encryption.  AES-NI, of course, is at least 15x faster than either of the other two.

How important is it that my implementation prevents timing attacks?  I'm wondering whether I should ditch my SSSE3 implementation and stick with straight C.

Comment: I would suggest using an existing library -- there are many available.  Is there any particular reason for writing your own?

Comment: it really depends on what you are using it for, timing attacks are most effective in a virtualized environment or in hardware, in many other cases, if the attacker has the ability to mount a timing attack, they have enough control of the system to read keystrokes and data from disk.

Comment: Also, I would suggest bitslicing &ndash; many applications do not need CBC mode, and bitslicing provides a large speed advantage.